# jQuery DatePicker Issue on Publish

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I am using a jQuery datepicker in my asp.net website. It works great on my computer and when deploying on my localhost. I deployed it out on our development server this evening and it works great and how it is suppose to on my computer, but on everyone elses the datepicker does not appear.

I was using this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
```

So I thought maybe I should download it and store it in the project itself, so I did so and after I replaced the above with:

```
<script src="../myScripts/jquery.minCAGVD940.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../myStyles/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And that still did not solve the issue.... Am I missing something? A setting? Anything? This is blowing my mind and can not seem to figure out why it is working on my machine and not  anyone elses, even after the above change....

Comment: Just for understanding, you are saying when you visit the site at your development server, it works but when someone else sees it, it doesn't work? Do you see any JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: That is correct, and no there are no JS errors in the console.... checked source as well and it looks like it is loading on theirs

Comment: Perhaps it's the browser, are they using the same browser as you are?

Comment: I have tried on pretty much every browser out there

Comment: Interesting, can you may be share the site just for testing if it is on the internet?

Comment: Have u tried your Datepicker script on JSFiddle..

Comment: Actually an intranet site, so I can't do that

Comment: It's just a hunch, but may be the URL to your jquery and and jquery-ui (which you downloaded) is not being resolved properly, while you are getting the script from the cache. I cannot think of any other reason why it shouldn't work on anyone else's machine if it is working on yours

Comment: So what would be a be an appropriate angle on debugging or resolving it?

Comment: The first step would be.run you site in google chrome. press f12(debug mode) and start debugging your script where you have declared the datepicker function

Comment: Create another page with only Datepicker, using CDN jquery path for css and scripts.

Comment: Here is a fiddle of my setup: http://jsfiddle.net/j7g01jky/

Comment: Its working in the fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71631/discussion-between-maxspan-and-codeboy).